# How to make an entire FullCalendar EventSource cell nonclickable

Tags: events, fullcalendar, clickable

I'm using event sources with FullCalendar 5. I need the cells containing events from one of the event sources to not be clickable.

I realize I can use eventClassNames or className to add a class for a given event source, but that class is added to the event text, not the cell, and nothing about the event source seems to be present as a selector at the cell level, either.

To summarize, the calendar is being used for reservations. If the date is present in a given event source, it is not available, so the cell should not be clickable. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: If you set those events to appear as background events, they'll cover the whole space in the slot. And then you can use the example [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap) to prevent selection of slots which contain a background event.

Comment: I think the way we need to use the calendar conflicts with this. We really just need it as a date picker, where the cell is clicked on to select that day. Some days should not be selectable, because they have already been selected, or because they are closed, or because it’s a holiday. We’re using an eventsource stream for each of those possibilities, because that’s the easiest way to get each set of dates to appear on the calendar. There are no actual time slots being used.

Comment: Well if your "slot" is 1 day long (which fullCalendar supports), then what I said above would still be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a check against existing events in the `select` callback - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback

so check that there is event(s) within the date range, *and* some custom property that identifies the source you wish to check for.

So when you import your events, have something like.

`sourceType: "a"`  / `sourceType: "b"`

Then in the select, do a check, here blocking selection if an event of sourceType "b" is found within the cell.

```
select: function( selectionInfo ) {         
    if(calendar.getEvents().filter(x => (x.start >= selectionInfo.start && x.end <= selectionInfo.end && x.extendedProps.sourceType == "b").length > 0) ) {
        calendar.unselect();
        selectionInfo.jsEvent.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    
    // your handler if selection is allowed goes here
}
```